# Need help for installing vulkan on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: vulkan

I am trying to install vulkan on the remote server.

**OS: Ubuntu 18.04**

**GPU: Nvidia GeForce RTX 2080ti**

**cuda version: 10.2**

**GPU driver version: 440.64**

First, I installed the SDK as following:

```
wget -qO - http://packages.lunarg.com/lunarg-signing-key-pub.asc | sudo apt-key add -   
sudo wget -qO /etc/apt/sources.list.d/lunarg-vulkan-bionic.list http://packages.lunarg.com/vulkan/lunarg-vulkan-bionic.list     
sudo apt update     
sudo apt install vulkan-sdk
```

These commands are from *https://vulkan.lunarg.com/doc/sdk/1.2.170.0/linux/getting_started_ubuntu.html*

After that, I ran command `vulkaninfo`, but it showed that the driver isn't installed properly. So I installed the driver as this `apt-get install mesa-vulkan-drivers`.

Then I ran `vulkaninfo` again. It showed

> 'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info
> error:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.
> ERROR at /build/vulkan-tools-1.2.162.1~rc1 1lunarg18.04/vulkaninfo/vulkaninfo.h:248:vkEnumerateInstanceExtensionProperties
> failed with ERROR_INITIALIZATION_FAILED

For the first line, I think it may not be a big deal so I ignored it.

And I tried 2 methods to fix the error

> error:XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set in the environment.

*Method1*: I ran the following 2 commands

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY vulkan
```

and

```
pkexec env DISPLAY=$DISPLAY XAUTHORITY=$XAUTHORITY vulkaninfo
```

But it showed

> Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Could not
> connect: No such file or directory

for both commands.

*Method2*
And I tried to add

```
Defaults        env_keep += "DISPLAY XAUTHORITY"
```

in sudoers file, but it didn't fix the problem.

Actually, I am new to vulkan and not very familiar with Ubuntu. I tried some commands above just because I found others used them to fix the same problem.

I wonder if I have installed the vulkan properly and the problem is about the configuration.
Or I didn't install vulkan completely.

---

Now I undid what I did before, and I just use

```
sudo apt-get install vulkan-utils
```

It seems that I installed vulkan, but when running

```
vulkaninfo
```

it shows

> ## ===========
> VULKAN INFO
>
> Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70
>
> Cannot create Vulkan instance.
> /build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:768: failed with
> VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER

How can I fix it without reinstalling my nvidia driver?

(Maybe the easiest way is to uninstall my driver now and install a new driver from https://developer.nvidia.com/vulkan-driver, but I can't uninstall my driver.)

Comment: `DISPLAY=DISPLAY` is a complete no-op if `DISPLAY` was not set in the first place. Are you running a GUI?

Comment: No, I have no GUI.

Comment: Yeah, thx. 
I think a GUI may help to fix the first line " 'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info". 
Do I have to have a GUI to install vulkan? 
(I edited the info after running "vulkaninfo", to make it more clearly)

Comment: The instructions you are following clearly require this. It's hard to imagine how you would use a graphics API without graphics.

Comment: I am trying to install Isaac Gym which needs vulkan and I am not sure why it needs it. I will try to install a GUI. Thank you!

Comment: I tried a GUI with the help of VNC viewer, and the first line `'DISPLAY' environment variable not set... skipping surface info` disappears now and the next two errors are still there. 
And the answer helps me to realize that my installing steps are wrong before. So I undid what I did before but encounter new issues as mentioned in the post now.

Answer (score 1):

Undo whatever you just did, and just follow the manual:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia#Installation

So, only install `nvidia-somenumber`, and that should be it.

- You do **not** need SDK, unless you are a developer
- `mesa-vulkan-drivers` is for AMD and Intel GPUs, so do **not** install that unless you have those
- do **not** screw your env unless you are pretty sure what you are doing
- if for some reason driver does not pull it in itself, you can install `vulkan-tools`, which will give you `vulkaninfo` and `vkcube` test apps

Comment: For some reason I can' t reinstall the Nvidia driver. When I run `apt-get install vulkan-tools`, it shows that `E: Unable to locate package vulkan-tools`.

Comment: I undid what I did, and just install `vulkan-utils`. And it outputs 
`
===========
VULKAN INFO
===========

Vulkan Instance Version: 1.1.70

Cannot create Vulkan instance.
/build/vulkan-UL09PJ/vulkan-1.1.70+dfsg1/demos/vulkaninfo.c:768: failed with VK_ERROR_INCOMPATIBLE_DRIVER`
now. 
How do I know the version of vulkan that is compatible with my nvidia driver version `440.64`. I found little information about it.

Comment: @VincentLeeWang That means your driver does not support Vulkan at all. Install reasonably recent proprietary driver per the link I gave you. Something like `nvidia-460` should work.

Comment: OK, but I wonder can I install it without uninstalling my now driver？

Comment: @VincentLeeWang If you use the settings GUI, it should manage things for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands - they worked for me and have enabled my Ubuntu to use the discrete graphics card as well as solve the issue of programs exiting when DXVK is activated.

Replace /home/user/GitHub with the folder where you'll put cloned Git repositories.

```
mkdir /home/user/GitHub
rm -rf /home/user/GitHub/Vulkan-Headers/
rm -rf /home/user/GitHub/Vulkan-ExtensionLayer/
sudo apt-get install -y cmake
sudo apt-get install -y make
sudo apt-get install -y meson
sudo apt-get install -y git
sudo apt-get install -y ninja-build
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y libx11-xcb-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libxkbcommon-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libwayland-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libxrandr-dev
sudo apt-get install -y libegl1-mesa-dev
sudo apt-get install -y xclip
cd /home/user/GitHub
git clone https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-Headers.git
cd Vulkan-Headers/
cmake -S . -B build/
cmake --install build --prefix build/install
cd /home/user/GitHub
git clone https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-ExtensionLayer.git
cd Vulkan-ExtensionLayer/
mkdir build
cd build
python3 ../scripts/update_deps.py --dir ../external --arch x64 --config debug
cmake -C ../external/helper.cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ..
cmake --build . --config Debug
sudo apt-get install -y linux-headers-$(uname -r)
sudo apt-get install -y pciutils
sudo apt-get install -y libvulkan1
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
sudo apt-get install -y libvulkan1
sudo apt-get install -y clang
sudo apt-get install -y vulkan-tools
sudo apt-get install -y vulkan-utils
sudo apt-get install -y mesa-vulkan-drivers
sudo apt-get install -y vulkan
vulkaninfo | grep -oP '(?<=Vulkan Instance Version: ).*' | xclip -selection clipboard
vul=$(xclip -selection clipboard -o)
sudo echo '{' > /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '    "file_format_version" : "1.0.0",' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '    "ICD": {' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '        "library_path": "libGLX_nvidia.so.0",' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '        "api_version" : "'$vul'"' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '    }' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo echo '}' >> /home/user/nvidia_icd.json
sudo cp /home/user/nvidia_icd.json /usr/share/vulkan/icd.d/
```

These commands worked for me, enabled Vulkan support as well as prevented integrated graphics from taking precedence in dgVoodoo2 over the Nvidia discrete graphics.

Hope this helps.